# Do comonoids in the closed monoidal category of topological spaces with the separate continuity product form a "nice" category of spaces?

Tags: general-topology, monoidal-categories, cartesian-closed-categories

The category of topological spaces $\mathbf{Top}$ can be made into a multicategory where maps $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \to Y$ are the maps $X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_n \to Y$ that are continuous in each variable holding the other variables fixed.

This multicategory is in fact represented by a closed monoidal structure on $\mathbf{Top}$, where the topology on $X \otimes Y$ is defined in such a way that a map $f:X \times Y \to Z$ is "separately continuous" (i.e. $f(x,-):Y \to Z$ and $f(-,y):X \to Z$ are continuous for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ respectively) if and only if $f$ is continuous from $X \otimes Y$ to $Z$, and $[X,Y]$ is the set of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$ considered as a subspace of the product space $Y^X$.

A topological space $X$ will then be a comonoid in this monoidal category if and only if the diagonal map $\Delta:X \to X \otimes X$ is continuous. This means equivalently that $f \circ \Delta:X \to Y$ is continuous for all separately continuous maps $f:X \times X \to Y$. Henceforth, the full subcategory consisting of such spaces will be denoted as $C$.

> Is $C$ a "nice" category of topological spaces (i.e. cartesian closed)?

It is easily seen that any Alexandrov space (where arbitrary intersections of open sets are open) belongs to $C$. In fact, if $X$ and $Y$ are two Alexandrov spaces, any separately continuous map from $X \times Y$ is in fact jointly continuous. There could also be some non-Alexandrov spaces in $C$, however.

Comment: An example that is not Alexandrov is $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by sets of the form $(-\infty,a)$.